# Adding a second View Controller to a single window application

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, nstableview

I have a single window application with multiple NSTableView items.
Originally I have been letting the same tableView data source methods, just switching based on the tableView passed. It has been recommended to me – and I agree – that it probably better to separate the view controllers for the tableViews (if not now, eventually as things get more complex).

I thought I will need to create a second ViewController class file and simply make the connections from the NSTableViews to that new ViewController class that will handle the data for the tableView but I cannot see how to make the connections in the storyboard.

What is the correct approach?
I would appreciate any hints or advice.
(I've searched for tutorials to help explain how this should best be done but cannot find anything relevant to what I'm trying to do.)

// MARK: - TableView Stuff

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
            
    var numberOfRows : Int = 0
    
    if tableView == mainTableView2 {
        print("number of rows for mainTableView2")
        numberOfRows = allFilesAsPaths.count
    } else if tableView == fileTypeTableView {
        print("number of rows for fileTypeTableView")
        numberOfRows = fileTypesDict.count
    } else if tableView == exifTableView {
        numberOfRows = exifData.count
        print("exifData.count = \(exifData.count)")
        print("number of rows for exifTableview \(numberOfRows)")
    }
    return numberOfRows
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    
    var val : String = ""
    
    if tableView == mainTableView2 {
    val = allFilesAsPaths[row]
    }
    if tableView == exifTableView {
        if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "tag" {
            let tagArray : [String] = Array(exifData.keys)
            val = tagArray[row]
        } else if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "value" {
            let valueArray : [String] = Array(exifData.values)
            val = valueArray[row]
        }
    }
    
    if tableView == fileTypeTableView {

    let types : [String] = Array(fileTypesDict.keys)
    let counts : [Int] = Array(fileTypesDict.values)

    if tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue == "type" {
            val = types[row]
        } else {
            val = String(counts[row])
        }
    }
    return val
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use any `NSViewController` functionality and will the view controller control the table view or is the view controller just the data source?

Comment: I’m thinking that it would implement The data source and delegate methods.

Comment: I can create a ViewController swift file but I don't understand how to make the storyboard connection between one NSTableView and the new view controller (I have three TableViews in the application's only window and I don't see how to connect just the one TableView to the new view controller).